Chronology Package conflicting with siunitx
Trying to add a basic timeline to a document. The chronology package appeared to be a good choice, but I'm getting a conflict with siunitx. The MWE will run as-is, but un-commenting the \usepackage{siunitx} gives the error: LaTeX cmd Error: Command '\unit' already defined. }
\documentclass[11 pt]{article}
\usepackage{chronology}
%\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
    \begin{chronology}[5]{1989}{2025}{\textwidth}[100ex]
        \eventpoint{\decimaldate{25}{8}{1991}}{Event One}[red][1][0.5]
        \eventpoint{\decimaldate{1}{5}{2011}}{Event Two}[red][1][0.5]
        \eventpoint{\decimaldate{5}{9}{2017}}{Event Three}[red][1][0.5]
    \end{chronology}
\end{document}


The package chronology makes a big mistake in definining internal parameters with user-space names.
In particular it does
\newlength{\unit}

for usage in internal macros, making it impossible for the user or other package to define \unit. The length is internal, as it's not even mentioned in the manual.
Solution: load siunitx first and change \unit into, say, \siunit. The code won't be reusable, but at least it works for your document.
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\NewCommandCopy{\siunit}{\unit}
\let\unit\relax

\usepackage{chronology}

\begin{document}

\begin{chronology}[5]{1989}{2025}{\textwidth}[100ex]
  \eventpoint{\decimaldate{25}{8}{1991}}{Event One}[red][1][0.5]
   \eventpoint{\decimaldate{1}{5}{2011}}{Event Two}[red][1][0.5]
   \eventpoint{\decimaldate{5}{9}{2017}}{Event Three}[red][1][0.5]
\end{chronology}

\siunit{\centi\meter}

\end{document}

Luckily, siunitx is well-written and doesn't use \unit internally, it just defines it at the outer level.
As an aside, the option is 11pt without spaces; the fact that it works also with a space should not be exploited, as it's completely incidental.

Thanks so much for the quick solution--and for noticing the errant space.
